# How can I toggle between mat-checkbox or mat-radio-button in Angular reactive form?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm creating a quiz app and need to toggle between mat-checkbox or mat-radio-button, depending on whether the question has one or more answers. Question #1 is a single choice answer question and shows with mat-radio-button whereas Question #2 is a multiple answer question but is also displaying with mat-radio-button instead of mat-checkbox.

This is how my template looks like:

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
    <ol *ngIf="multipleAnswer === false">
        // using mat-radio-buttons here 
    </ol>
    <ol *ngIf="multipleAnswer === true">
        // using mat-checkboxes here
    </ol>
</form>
```

and in my ts file the logic looks like:

```
multipleAnswer: boolean;

ngOnInit() {
  this.multipleAnswer = this.quizService.getQuestionType();
}

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
  if (changes.question) {
    switch (this.question.type) {
      case 'SINGLE_CHOICE':
        this.formGroup = new FormGroup({
          answer: new FormControl([null, Validators.required])
        });
        break;
      case 'MULTIPLE_CHOICE':
        const multipleChoiceValidator = (control: AbstractControl) =>
          control.value.reduce(
            (valid: boolean, currentValue: boolean) => valid || currentValue
            , false
          ) ? null : {answers: 'At least one answer needs to be checked!'};
        this.formGroup = new FormGroup({
          answers: this.formBuilder.array(this.question.shuffledAnswers
              .map((answer: string) => this.formBuilder.control(false)),
            multipleChoiceValidator
          ),
        });
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

don't need shuffledAnswers, question type should be inferred from the assets/quiz.ts file (shouldn't need to hard code the question type), and answers should be numbers, not strings

in my QuizService:

```
getQuestionType(): boolean {
  return (this.correctAnswers && this.correctAnswers.length === 1);
}
```

Comment: I can't see your full code so i'll guess. Maybe the problem is you are checking `multipleAnswer` only once, inside `ngOnInit`. Did you try to check it in `ngOnChanges`?

Comment: yes I added it to ngOnChanges, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I added the new ngOnChanges code shown above, but getting this error in the console: core.js:6237 ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(QuizRoutingModule)[FormBuilder -> FormBuilder -> FormBuilder -> FormBuilder]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for FormBuilder!

Comment: I can't say much from this sorry. Maybe if you can share the relevant parts as a stackblitz we can inspect that.

Comment: please see my stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-quiz-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems. First, calling `multipleAnswer` only inside `ngOnInit` sets this boolean variable only once at begining, it should be inside `ngOnChanges`.

But it's not the only issue here, the main problem is in your `QuizService`. Here you use `this.quizService.getQuestionType();` method to set `multipleAnswer` true or false but inside your `getQuestionType()` method of QuizService you are checking `this.correctAnswers` if set and has element length of 1 but `this.correctAnswers` is always empty when you call it.

Another problem is in your `ngOnChanges` you have `switch (this.question.type)` here `this.question` seems to be undefined evertime.

Edit your code like below and check console outputs everytime a question appears.

Add a new method the get `correctAnswers` from a question.

```
getCorrectAnswers(question:QuizQuestion){
   return question.options.filter((item)=> item.correct);
}
```

And edit begining of ngOnChanges like below, i also added a console output so you can see the data from the new method above.

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {   
   if (changes.question && changes.question.currentValue !== changes.question.firstChange){
     this.currentQuestion = changes.question.currentValue;
     this.correctAnswers = this.getCorrectAnswers(this.currentQuestion);
     this.multipleAnswer = this.correctAnswers.length > 1 ? true : false;
     console.log('correct ans: ', this.correctAnswers);
     ...
```

I can't modify all of the code since you have your own logic behind your code, but i updated the answer so that variables related to this problem set correctly inside 'ngOnChanges`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am still a little stuck. I've updated my stackblitz by adding this.multipleAnswer = this.correctAnswers.length > 1 ? true : false; to ngOnChanges (instead of using quizservice) and added the pushing of correctAnswers within the setSelected function. It seems like sometimes it works fine and sometimes it doesn't. The second question should use checkboxes (and should only select the first and second questions as correct answers).

Comment: Updated the answer and also forked your stackblitz and applied the solution. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-quiz-app-phgyaq

Comment: Thank you, but now I noticed that all the answers are now selecting as correct, and in the second question when answered correctly the score is not increasing.

Comment: Well, as i said in the answer,i  can't modify all of the code since you have your own logic behind your code. But, you should adjust other parts of your code according to the changes we made, which is, when question changes you calculate everything inside ngOnChanges. For example you have setSelected method which is fired when radio button changed, there is still some calculation coming from quizService, check those if they are serving as intended.

Comment: Yea, I was able to fix the error easily, it was because the mat-radio-group and mat-checkbox-group were disabled. I could use some help with the mat-checkbox question (Question 2) doesn't seem to be incrementing when the correct answers are chosen.

Comment: Well, afaik, there is no such thing like `mat-checkbox-group` therefore there is no `(change)` event for that element. It's not firing the `checkboxChange` and hence the component doesn't emit the necessary data that you bind to `answer` property on your main component. So it fails the condition inside `checkIfAnsweredCorrectly()`  method and does not increase the variable on your service.

Comment: Also even checking this chain of events and data transmissions are so confusing. You should manage the data on your main component  using the service and input the neccessary data to your child components which only should be responsible with displaying the data like your scoreboard component, this component shouldn't need to know anything about the service or how the score data is received.

Comment: I removed the mat-check-group but still not sure how to fix the problem of the score not incrementing for correct answers on the checkbox question.

Comment: Removing it means you can't still trigger the `checkboxChange()`. Actually you don't need any of `radioChange()` and `checkboxChange()`, remove both and add `this.answer.emit(optionIndex);` at the begining of `setSelected()` since you already call this when any answer input changed.